# Table-valued parameter "The Parameter @Queues cannot be declared READONLY since its is not a table-valued parameter"

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying my first crack at table-valued parameters, and I'm constantly getting the following error:

> The Parameter @Queues cannot be declared READONLY since its is not a table-valued parameter

I'm trying to create the stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateQueues
     (@Queues AS dbo.Queues READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    -- do something
END
GO
```

The `Queues` table does exist in SQL in the `dbo` schema (we use it extensively) and the database compatibility level is @ 100 (I tried another copy of the DB with a level of 140, also didn't work).

Does the table itself have to be modified somehow? Is there a database level feature that must be turned on?

Thanks

Comment: You need to declare a *separate* user-defined table type (whose column list *may* match `Queues`) and use that as the type of the parameter. But I'm surprised you've gotten this far in learning about table-valued parameters and not always seem such a type being declared.

Comment: yeah know, sometimes you just miss the simple things.  I did all those tables being created, but i glanced over them, thinking they were just showing the table being created, not that it was a separate object!  Soon as i added that, the error vanished.  Its the little things.....